# Ask user for SIM Card PIN

Tags: android, sim-card

I searched for a question similar to this one, but no luck.

I'm writing an app which, in order to correctly authenticate the user, it should ask him to input the correct SIM Card. Is it possible, or will I have to user another PIN just for the app authentication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if it is possible, but as there are devices out there that have no SIM (think tablets with WLAN only), it may be a better idea to have a different PIN that is not SIM-related.

Comment: Yes, I'm considering that hypothesis. If a SIM card is present, the app asks for it; if not, user is able to choose his own PIN.