# Check SIM PIN with SDK Android

Tags: android, sim-card

My app needs to check the pin inserted by a user with the SIM card pin and that Android has to  answer me if the pin inserted is correct. I only need to check, never change the code pin.

It is possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ask user for SIM Card PIN](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5618999/ask-user-for-sim-card-pin)

Comment: My idea is to do the request PIN from my app when the phone turns on. My app is a Home app. I want to replace the Android request PIN by the request PIN from my app.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it can be done, but:

I would not rely on a SIM card being present - think of tablets with WiFi only. 
Also as a user I would not trust any application that would ask for the pin of my SIM card.

Comment: My idea is to do the request PIN from my app when the phone turns on. My app is a Home app. I want to replace the Android request PIN by the request PIN from my app.