# Check SIMCards's PIN

Tags: android, gsm, ussd

So I've research this subject and I didn't get much information, even though I did read a few threads here like [Check SIM PIN with SDK Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9128627/check-sim-pin-with-sdk-android) and [Ask user for SIM Card PIN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5618999/ask-user-for-sim-card-pin) but neither of them really answer the question - the app I'm trying to write is based on USSD and will run on devices with SIMCards.

I also read the thread [Use system PIN dialog in Android application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10106837/use-system-pin-dialog-in-android-application), but I'm not trying to overwrite the OS, I'm just trying to write a simple app that can check an entered String against the SIMCard PIN. On this last thread, a user (a.ch.) said that trying to access or even check the SIMCard PIN number is not allowed by the OS (at least without modifications, I suppose). Can you guys confirm or give me a link that mentions this prohibition?

Also, is it possible to, using only USSD, check the PIN? For example, I only know the MMI code to change PIN:
**04*Current PIN * New PIN * New PIN#.
And this actually returns fail or sucess messages, and if I make Current PIN = New PIN, I can actually identify if the PIN I introduced is correct or not, but I see this on a text message. Does the smartphone return this info in a attribute that I can check? How can I access the return code?

I need all the help I can get :)

Comment: This should give you a little headway: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25784141/android-set-or-reset-sim-card-pin-code-programmatically

Comment: I actually read that, but it doesn't help me that much because I honestly don't know what the supplyPin does internally. All the documentation I've read about supplyPin mentions locking or unlocking the phone, so I guess that does more than I want. What would happen if I input the wrong PIN? Would it lock my phone? (I don't want that). Does that only work when SIM_STATE_PIN_REQUIRED or SIM_STATE_PUK_REQUIRED are true?
I didn't get the answer for this during my reading.

Anyway, it's not about locking my phone or not... all I'd like, if it's possible, is a PIN check, that's it.

Comment: Hm.  Thinking about this more, to be honest, I'm not sure that it's possible.  I can't find an API anywhere that enables direct reference to the PIN - everything is just unlock SIM or replace PIN.

Comment: Yes, that's the conclusion I'm reaching too. Of course the phone does this, but I suppose, for security purposes, they don't even allow the developer to check the PIN (I could easily make a brute-force app to test all the PINs and get the right one). What about getting a response from USSD/MMI, is only returns text or do you know if the MMI to change the PIN returns a code that allows me to distinguish what happened?

Comment: I just found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19066677/how-to-get-response-from-ussd-code-from-android
I suppose it's not possible to manage USSD responses in Android, right?

Comment: Correct.  I'm at the same conclusion - for security reasons, it's all unavailable to call directly.